# Does this matrix operation hold?

Tags: matrices

Suppose A is an nxn matrix and b is a constant scalar.
t is some natural number >0

Can i apply binomial expansion on (A-Ib)^t?

Comment: May I know, what  $I$ is?

Comment: @RaziehNoori Identity matrix.

Comment: @Razieh Noori, yes, I should have clarified. I is the identity matrix of dimensions nxn.

Comment: column matrix nx1 product nxn? is it possible?

Comment: $bI$ does not exist if $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. If so, $Ib$ exists but is not of the same dimension as $A$. So $A-bI$ is not defined, nor is $A-Ib$.

Comment: How do you propose to subtract a vector from a matrix in the first place?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i meant Ib.

Comment: I can subtract it because I multiplied it by the identity matrix first so that its the same dimensions as A.

Comment: n×n . n×1 then you have n×1 matrix, and $A$ is n×n. still impossible operation

Comment: Oops you're right. I was supposed to write b is a constant scalar.

Comment: for constant scaler it is obvious. because $A$ and $I$ commute

Answer (score 0):

you can use binomial theorem for any commutative ring or for any two elements in a ring which commute.Also observe(A-bI)^t have no meaning(matrix addition is not compatible)